# The expected Spring JPA query is not being returned

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm learning how to use Spring JPA and am have configured my database to successfully add elements to my database.  I'm just having trouble formulating a query to retrieve my results (a list of Employee, filtered by lastname):

//Employee entity:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public Employee() { }

    public Employee(long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

And my problem is within the query in my repository interface below.  When invoking the `findByLastName(String lastName)` method, I'm always receiving an empty Collection -- even when passing a lastName that I know exists in my database:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository
    extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("select u from Employee u where u.lastName = ?1")
    public Collection<Employee> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that the column i'm querying is named `last_name` in my database column (with underscores). I'm not sure if this makes any difference.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need add @Column on the field to let jpa know how to create the mappings between database and java class.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="target_table_name")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    //getter and setter and something else
}
```

Without @Table,the entity's name will be recognized by jpa as the table name.If they are not same,you should add @Table on the class and specify the table name.

"first_name" and "last_name" in the annotation is the actual name of the database column,you should change it if necessary.

By the way,it's better to set the access of entities' fields as private.

Comment: I modified my `Employee` class accordingly, but am still not getting any values returned when invoking the `findByLastName(...)` method. Any other thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Comment: ....Did you add @Table on the class?Make sure you're dealing with the correct table and scheme~

Comment: I just added it -- still no luck

Comment: It turned out to be an unrelated problem with the RestController that was passing the query parameter into the `findByLastName(...)` method. Nonetheless, the changes you suggested were also needed in order to successfully query the DB.

Comment: So can jpa generate the sql when you invoke the method?You cloud set the log level to trace to get more info.

Comment: The "@Column" annotations do nothing in our case since the provider will automatically map the camel case Entity fields to snake case database columns.

Comment: @garfield it's true jpa has a default name convert strategy.But before doing it,it's hard to say it's not the true problem.